Ubuntu 24.4. Acer Travelmate P416-52G Ethernet won't work after sleep / suspend
I experience this:
Laptop connected to ethernet. Working smoothly. It goes to sleep (I put it to sleep or the timer does) and when it comes back up, ethernet is down.
I found several solutions on the web, spent maybe 3 hours on it, but nothing worked so far...so I am asking here.
I have been using Ubuntu for maybe 10 years, but I am still no a pro on terminal use...
I found a solution somewhere, where the idea was to write a script (or rather include somewhere) that the ethernet-device should be shut down, when laptop goes to sleep and restart, when it reawakens. However, the described way to do it, didnt work on my system. (Because the path didnt exist on my system (maybe older version of Ubuntu?)).
I should mention, that everything works fine again after a reboot.
> > clara@clara-TravelMate-P416-52G:~$ sudo lshw -C network
>     [sudo] Passwort für clara: 
>       *-network DEAKTIVIERT     
>        Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
>        Produkt: Raptor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
>        Hersteller: Intel Corporation
>        Physische ID: 14.3
>        Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:14.3
>        Logischer Name: wlp0s20f3
>        Version: 01
>        Seriennummer: 28:a0:6b:f2:1e:17
>        Breite: 64 bits
>        Takt: 33MHz
>        Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>        Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-50-generic firmware=86.fb5c9aeb.0
> so-a0-gf-a0-86.uc latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
>        Ressourcen: iomemory:610-60f irq:16 memory:61382d4000-61382d7fff   *-network
>        Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
>        Produkt: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
>        Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>        Physische ID: 0
>        Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:7a:00.0
>        Logischer Name: enp122s0
>        Version: 1b
>        Seriennummer: 74:d4:dd:7e:a2:8d
>        Größe: 100Mbit/s
>        Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
>        Breite: 64 bits
>        Takt: 33MHz
>        Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd
> autonegotiation
>        Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-50-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2
> 02/26/15 ip=192.168.178.62 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
> port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
>        Ressourcen: irq:16 ioport:3000(Größe=256) memory:63a04000-63a04fff memory:63a00000-63a03fff
> clara@clara-TravelMate-P416-52G:~$

Here comes the output, after reawakening from sleep:
clara@clara-TravelMate-P416-52G:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] Passwort für clara: 
  *-network DEAKTIVIERT     
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: Raptor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 14.3
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:14.3
       Logischer Name: wlp0s20f3
       Version: 01
       Seriennummer: 28:a0:6b:f2:1e:17
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-50-generic firmware=86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-gf-a0-86.uc latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       Ressourcen: iomemory:610-60f irq:16 memory:61382d4000-61382d7fff
  *-generic
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:7a:00.0
       Logischer Name: enp122s0
       Version: ff
       Seriennummer: 74:d4:dd:7e:a2:8d
       Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
       Breite: 32 bits
       Takt: 66MHz
       Fähigkeiten: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-50-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       Ressourcen: irq:16 ioport:3000(Größe=256) memory:63a04000-63a04fff memory:63a00000-63a03fffclara@clara-TravelMate-P416-52G:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] Passwort für clara: 
  *-network DEAKTIVIERT     
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: Raptor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 14.3
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:14.3
       Logischer Name: wlp0s20f3
       Version: 01
       Seriennummer: 28:a0:6b:f2:1e:17
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-50-generic firmware=86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-gf-a0-86.uc latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       Ressourcen: iomemory:610-60f irq:16 memory:61382d4000-61382d7fff
  *-generic
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:7a:00.0
       Logischer Name: enp122s0
       Version: ff
       Seriennummer: 74:d4:dd:7e:a2:8d
       Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
       Breite: 32 bits
       Takt: 66MHz
       Fähigkeiten: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-50-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       Ressourcen: irq:16 ioport:3000(Größe=256) memory:63a04000-63a04fff memory:63a00000-63a03fff

Sorry for the german system :-)
I am grateful for any suggestions.

How can I (manually / i.e. in the terminal) deactivate and activate single modules in my system? Like for example the ethernet controller?
